# Is the Arctic already ice-free during summer?

Tags: arctic

Not an expert in this field but I'm just curious as to how accurate the Google Map is [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Chile/@64,130.5468889,2.43z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x9662c5410425af2f:0x505e1131102b91d!8m2!3d-35.675147!4d-71.542969)

Also, from the [interview](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/aug/21/arctic-will-be-ice-free-in-summer-next-year) with scientist Peter Wadhams, his estimate seems to be spot-on.

I still remember, as a kid, we used to draw a white landmass when illustrating the Polar North. Now, I think we'll have to teach the kids to draw wavy lines, representing the Arctic Ocean instead!

Comment: the inteview is from 2016 we are in 2019 now and it is still some ice in the arctic now even if it is a lot less than normal for this time of year.

Comment: @trondhansen Peter did clarify on that point in the interview. You would still have some ice left hugging the coast etc. but the ocean surface is ice-free. The thing is, I'm not too sure if Google Maps accurately displays the area to be fully ice-free. Too much clouds in the satellite view to be able to tell properly, for my untrained eyes. And by the way, we're still months away from the height of summer!

Comment: you can follow the sea ice extent here http://polarportal.dk/en/sea-ice-and-icebergs/ and here http://nsidc.org/arcticseaicenews/ there is a lot of things you can not see in google or other maps.

Comment: @trondhansen Thanks! Excellent resource! I can see that the ice sheet is still there. It looks like most of it already almost thinned out some time in August last year.

Comment: @trondhansen can you convert your comment with the links into an answer ? So people can upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the sea ice extent here at http://polarportal.dk/en/sea-ice-and-icebergs/

And here at http://nsidc.org/arcticseaicenews/

There is a lot of things you can not see in regular maps as they fill in the area with ice as open sea on their products,It is the same for land areas too they do not change the maps if the ground is covered by snow.

So the answer to your question,There is still an ice cover in the arctic even if it is starting to get dangerously low at the end of summer.

As a side note it does look like the arctic ice cover is melting a lot faster this year than what it have done the last ten years on average,You can see a more detailed and year by year graph here https://nsidc.org/arcticseaicenews/charctic-interactive-sea-ice-graph/ for both arctic and antarctic sea ice

Comment: I think that graph makes it really clear. We seem to be pushing that 2 standard deviation boundary since 2007. Among changes in the past decade that came to mind: 1. proliferation of budget airlines 2. rise of the internet leading to massive data centers.